# Serial Communication - strtok() issue

Tags: serial, uart

I'm working on UART communication between an ESP32 (sender) and ESP8266 NodeMCU board(receiver).

The host is sending out the following character string:

```
Serial.println("2753192144$1&");
```

The `2753192144` is the payload. The `$1&` is the trailer of the packet - `$1` signifies a particular option for the receiver and `&` is the termination character to signify that the packet is complete.

On the receiver end - this is what I have:

```
#define MAX_REC_STR_SIZE 10
#define REC_TRAILER_SIZE 4 // $1& and string terminator
#define TRUE_TRAILER_SIZE 2 // option size really

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available()){
    char data [MAX_REC_STR_SIZE + TRUE_TRAILER_SIZE + 1];
    Serial.readBytesUntil('&', data, MAX_REC_STR_SIZE + REC_TRAILER_SIZE); // data does not contain termination &
    data[MAX_REC_STR_SIZE + TRUE_TRAILER_SIZE + 1] = 0; // adding null terminator

    // Tokenizing
    char *payload = strtok(data, "$"); // getting payload
    char opt = strtok(NULL, "$")[0]; // getting option - 1 in our sample

    // Print
    Serial.println(payload);
    Serial.println(opt);
  }
}
```

**This code results in a stack exception error in the serial monitor**. If I remove the last line which prints `opt`, the payload print works fine and I get `2753192144`in the serial output.

I tested this exact code out in a standard C compiler, except instead of the serial read part - I defined a character array with `2753192144$1&` and used `printf` instead of `Serial.println`. See the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char data[] = "2753192144$1";

    char *payload = strtok(data, "$");
    char opt = strtok(NULL, "$")[0];
    printf("Payload is %s and opt is %c", payload, opt);

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs

```
Payload is 2753192144 and opt is 1
```

This works fine. Any ideas why the Arduino sketch isn't working?

Comment: There are a number of "handy" functions, for example the readBytesUntil. They have a timeout. You can use those once, when you are a beginner. But after that you have to move on and place the characters in a buffer as soon as a character is available. One character at a time for every iteration of the arduino loop. Check if the buffer has enough data en then process the data in the buffer. When you expect 16 bytes, make a buffer of 40 bytes and prevent that it overflows. Your code is dangerous in a number of ways.

Comment: `println` sends two additional characters that will mess with your fixed message size. Also you have a buffer for 13 character, but put a limit on `readBytesUntil` to 14 characters.

Comment: @gre_gor Ah yes. That REC_TRAILER_SIZE in the readBytesUntil() should be TRUE_TRAILER_SIZE since the & itself isn't meant to be read.

Comment: @Jot Yeah. I noticed that a lot of people in other threads were manually reading data and was wondering why not many people were using this readBytesUntil() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
data[MAX_REC_STR_SIZE + TRUE_TRAILER_SIZE + 1] = 0; // adding null terminator
```

That line places a 0 in the byte *following* the array.

If you define an array of size [x] you have slices [0] to [x-1] available. If you try accessing [x] you will be altering other items on the stack after the array.

That's called a *buffer overrun* and is one of the most common causes of programs crashing.

If you want to put a 0 at the end of the array, you should use

```
data[MAX_REC_STR_SIZE + TRUE_TRAILER_SIZE] = 0; // adding null terminator
```

You should also check that the `strtok()` calls actually return a valid pointer. If the incoming string is not in the right format and `strtok()` can't split the string up, it will return NULL. If you then try and access that NULL pointer as if it were a valid array you will have a nasty crash.

Comment: Ah yes. My mistake sorry. Let me make some amendments to the code to take into account all the comments.

Comment: I made that change. Didn't change anything. I added a check to see if a NULL was being returned by either other of the two strtok() commands. Code runs fine I use the char opt = strtok() line without doing any operations with it. But even checking if it's NULL crashes the program.

Comment: I printed out the strlen() of data and it's 12 so that must mean that includes the 10 digit payload and the $1. Not sure why the second strtok() is giving me so much trouble. Technically, the second strtok() should only be returning 1 character - the '1'.

Comment: UPDATE: `char opt = strtok(NULL, "$")[0];` to `char *opt = strtok(NULL, "$")` seems to have fixed it some how. Not entirely sure why the first didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be something strange in the c library for the ESP8266. I don't know which it uses, but it certainly won't be the same as your PC...

Comment: Very well could be. It's really weird. Printing it as opt[0] works too with my new line of code. For some reason, I just can't assign it like this - `char opt = strtok(NULL, "$")[0];` Thanks for the help though. I appreciate it